# How to Read Login Message From GPS Tracker Mini GT06

Tags: c#, sockets, gps

I Want to Develop a Terminal In C# to get Data From Gps Tracker
Protocol Documentation : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q3xy-LHjpCpuScAI6DPIKEWL1X3IyLC1/view

I Also Write a Code to Recive a data But No Luck

Please Help Me In this.

```
        static void MainX()
    {
        Process.GetProcessesByName("LINQPad.UserQuery").Where(x => x.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Kill());

        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8201);
        listener.Start();
        write("Server started...");

        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            write("Client " + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString() + " connected");
            var stream = client.GetStream();
            var br = new BinaryReader(stream);
            var bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int header = br.ReadInt16();

                    if (header == 0x7979)
                    {
                        int length = br.ReadByte();
                        int dataLength = length - 5;
                        int type = br.ReadByte();

                        write("Yes we Get Sonmething");


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                write("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }

            client.Close(); write("Client disconnected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The device is a server (listener) and your c# application is client.  You have TCPListener instead of TCPClient.